# merging two tables by common column

Tags: python, file-io, python-2.7, file-handling

Suppose i have two files , having data

table1.txt contents

```
avvd, 1234, ufgh
klpn, 5678, oppr
srtv, 9abc, pxyz
```

table2.txt contents

```
abcd, 1234, efgh
klmn, 5678, opqr
stuv, 9abc, wxyz
```

Now I want to get merge them , because their second column is same , and show the result.

Desired output is if table1.txt and table2.txt columns are same then merge both tables and make them one and show them in output

```
avvd, 1234, ufgh, abcd, efgh
klpn, 5678, oppr, klmn, opqr
srtv, 9abc, pxyz, stuv, wxyz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#input

file1 = open('1.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('2.txt', 'r')
matrix1 = [line.rstrip().split(', ') for line in file1.readlines()]
matrix2 = [line.rstrip().split(', ') for line in file2.readlines()]
file1.close()
file2.close()

#combine

t_matrix1 = [[r[col] for r in matrix1] for col in range(len(matrix1[0]))]
t_matrix2 = [[r[col] for r in matrix2] for col in range(len(matrix2[0]))]
final_t_matrix = []
for i in (t_matrix1 + t_matrix2):
    if i not in final_t_matrix:
        final_t_matrix.append(i)
final_matrix = [[r[col] for r in final_t_matrix] for col in range(len(final_t_matrix[0]))]

#output

outfile = open('out.txt', 'w')
for i in final_matrix:               
    for j in i[:-1]:
        outfile.write(j+', ')
    outfile.write(i[-1]+'\n')
outfile.close()
```